# Can you get access to MS Office 365 Word save document event?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365, office365api, office365-apps

For Office 365 Word add-ins, is there a Save event (similar to something in windows programming, like Saving() or Saved())?  In other words is there a way\time\event to detect when user is trying to save a document?

Answer (score 2):

the fast answer to this question is that this is not supported as of now. please help us improve our APIs by voting or adding this request here https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word

Also please share your scenario, its specially interesting in your question Office365 Word, in the online clients saving a document is a constant operation, not sure what you intend to do on such events.

thanks

Comment: Thank you for the reply, much appreciated. I would like to have a "hook" into the saving event so that I can judge\decide if I should augment the data\properties\etc of that document. Next the API I was going to ask for was printing, but if you don't have save, I'm assuming you don't have print neither?

Comment: no we dont have print either :(  please also add it to uservoice